# Ejecutar uno o varios comandos sudo con PHP 7+

Tags: php, linux

Mi objectivo es ejecutar varios comandos sudo con PHP , usando `exec_shell()`, probe de varias formas y me pide contraseña cosa que no se como manejar desde PHP (y seria inseguro hacer echo de mi root psswd), el tipo de comando que necesito ejecutar son `systemctl start/stop mi_servicio.service` almenos para 5 servicios, he probado haciendo `$test = shell_exec("sudo -u root systemctl stop mi_servicio.service");` pero me pide pass , no se como podria hacer para que al ejecutar no pidiese contraseña, a ver, en `visudo` tendria que hacer algo como `www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: $cmd`
pero dicha solucion no creo que sea adecuada , porque son 5 servicios , ademas no sabria que poner en `$cmd`.
He tenido otras ideas como crear un .sh que segun los parametros que se le pase ejecute unos u otros comandos y editar visudo para que no se requiera pass para ese script, pero tampoco es del todo adecuada para mi la solucion.

Por otra parte, cabe otra posibilidad pero no he encontrado nada para ello ,y es que , estes comandos tienen que ser ejecutar a causa de que yo edito un archivo de configuracion el cual leen ciertos scripts mios usando

`. /home/jorge/proyecto/config.ini`, esa posibilidad seria crear un script que detectase si se ha hecho un cambio en ese archivo config.ini y con "if's" ejecutar el comando para reiniciar el servicio correspondiente al script que le afecte ese cambio.

Comment: podes usar [`inotifywait`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) de [`inotify-tools`](https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools/wiki#inotifywait-example-1-thanks-to-nick-lothian) para monitorear si el archivo fue modificado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar [`inotifywait`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) de [`inotify-tools`](https://github.com/inotify-tools/inotify-tools/wiki#inotifywait-example-1-thanks-to-nick-lothian) para monitorear si el archivo fue modificado.

`monitorearINI.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

while inotifywait -e modify /home/jorge/proyecto/config.ini; do
service apache2 restart
done
```

Arrancas el watcher con sudo

```
$ sudo ./monitorearINI.sh
```

y si modificas el archivo desde otra consola (o php ) vas a ver algo así:

```
$ sudo ./monitorearINI.sh
[sudo] password for alejandro:
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
/home/jorge/proyecto/config.ini MODIFY
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
```

Comment: podrias ayudarme con esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/408978/ante-inotifywait-solo-realiza-acciones-la-primera-vez