# Problema con un while y inotifywait [Shell]

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Tengo un servicio que ejecuta un script , este se encarga de comprobar que ante un cambio en un archivo de configuracion, si cierto servicio esta activo , lo reinicie, solo 1 de los 2 servicios puede estar activo.
Pero al parecer ante una moficiacion , en vez de reiniciar el servicio correspondiente, solo lo hace la primera vez que haya una modificacion.
Y no se como arreglarlo, este es el codigo:

```
#!/bin/bash


servicio_A=$(sudo systemctl status mi_servicioA.target)
servicio_B=$(sudo systemctl status mi_servicioB.target)

while inotifywait -e modify /home/proyecto/config.ini; do

        if echo "$servicio_A" | grep -q "Active: active" ; then

                sudo systemctl stop mi_servicioA.target
                sleep 1
                sudo systemctl start mi_servicioA.target
                sleep 10 

        else if echo "$servicio_B" | grep -q "Active: active" ;then
                sudo systemctl stop mi_servicioB.target
                sleep 1
                sudo systemctl start mi_servicioB.target
        fi
fi
done
```

```
Nov 22 20:38:19 raspberrypi sudo[255]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0
Nov 22 20:38:22 raspberrypi sudo[255]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 22 20:38:23 raspberrypi sudo[331]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/syst
Nov 22 20:38:23 raspberrypi sudo[331]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0
Nov 22 20:38:24 raspberrypi sudo[331]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 22 20:38:24 raspberrypi changes_config.sh[252]: Setting up watches.
Nov 22 20:38:24 raspberrypi changes_config.sh[252]: Watches established.
Nov 22 20:47:29 raspberrypi changes_config.sh[252]: /home/proyecto/config.ini MODIFY
Nov 22 20:47:30 raspberrypi changes_config.sh[252]: Setting up watches.
Nov 22 20:47:30 raspberrypi changes_config.sh[252]: Watches established.
```

Comment: probá mover el `systemctl status` dentro del while así lo revisa cada vez que ejecuta el loop, aunque si podés editar los `.service` de cada servicio ahí podés definir un restart o reload ( para restart hay un sleep si mal no recuerdo )

Comment: perfecto me sirvio meter las variables (status ) dentro del while

Comment: si quieres publica la respuesta y te acepto la respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inotifywait` frena el proceso del script hasta que tiene algo para reportar, el valor devuelto sigue evaluado a `true` por el `while` convirtiéndolo en un loop infinito salvo que haya error crítico, esto significa que habría que chequear el `status` de los servicios dentro del `while` para tomar las decisiones con info fresca, algo así:

```
#!/bin/bash

while inotifywait -e modify /home/proyecto/config.ini; do
  servicio_A=$(sudo systemctl status mi_servicioA.target)
  servicio_B=$(sudo systemctl status mi_servicioB.target)

  if echo "$servicio_A" | grep -q "Active: active" ; then

    sudo systemctl stop mi_servicioA.target
    sleep 1
    sudo systemctl start mi_servicioA.target
    sleep 10 

    else if echo "$servicio_B" | grep -q "Active: active" ;then
      sudo systemctl stop mi_servicioB.target
      sleep 1
      sudo systemctl start mi_servicioB.target
    fi
  fi
done
```

Tener en cuenta que el sudo por lo general tiene un timeout donde vuelve a pedir credenciales, en ese caso lanzar el script principal con `sudo` así las cosas dentro del `while` también van con ese contexto.